# How does the expansion around the free theory relate to the idea of Gaussian fixed point in RG?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I have been wondering about the relationship between the Wilsonian picture of renormalisation, and the perturbative picture for quite some time now (in the context of QFT).

What I am puzzled about most is how much the notion of a IR Gaussian fixed point and the possibility of low-energy perturbative expansions are related.

(1) In QCD, the theory is perturbatively ill-defined at low energies, and at the same time said to emanate from a Gaussian fixed point in the UV.

(2) In 4-dimensional $\phi^4$-theory, the theory is perturbatively well-defined at low energies, and at the same time said to run into a Gaussian fixed point (albeit with not necessarily zero mass term) in the IR (as far as I understand).

Is the more general observation I derive from this (``the perturbative approach at low energies requires there to be an IR Gaussian fixed point“) true?

Comment: In $4 - \epsilon$ dimensions for $\phi^4$ theory, there is a Wilson-Fisher fixed point which is not Gaussian. However, perturbative approach at low energies is still valid for small enough $\epsilon$.